# Using a mutex semaphore between two tasks

Tags: c++, c, semaphore, vxworks

I am trying to understand just how to use semaphores in general. I have chosen a mutex type semaphore instead of a binary in order to maintain task priorities. The synopsis is:

I have two tasks, WebTask and DBTask.

WebTask is a simple task that takes (can you guess) web requests and does something with them.

DBTask is a (you got it) database task that runs on a messaging queue type system, so in order to work with it, you must send a message to its queue with n arguments.

Here is how things need to go down

1. WebTask receives an input and wants to get data from DBTask.
2. WebTask constructs a message for DBTask and sends it along the main messaging system with DBTask's id and all arguments
3. WebTask must wait for DBTask to

   1. Receive the message
   2. Talk to the database
   3. Format the result

Without semaphores, here's what is happening

1. WebTask constructs and sends msg
2. WebTask continues on
3. DBTask gets msg
4. DBTask talks to database, gets data, etc

So obviously they are out of sync (should be 1,3,4,2)

This is just one thing I tried that I thought would work..

1. WebTask create a new mutex semaphore
2. WebTask constructs and sends a msg, while also telling DBTask about the semaphore ID
3. WebTask takes the semaphore
4. DBTask gets msg
5. DBTask processes msg
6. DBTasks gives back semaphore

This changed nothing.

What I don't understand at all (after many attempts).

1. Who should be in charge of the semaphore? Who should create it?
2. When is the semaphore taken?
3. When is the semaphore given?

(Notes: I am on VxWorks)

Comment: Read this: [Ask],  and this: [MCVE]

Comment: A mutex is not a semaphore. It is possible to implement a semaphore using a mutex and a condition variable however.

Comment: @JiveDadson Mutex Semaphores are one of the 3 or 4 semaphore types provided by the VxWorks OS. These are designed to provide mutual exclusion around a shared resource, binary semaphores are better used for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do your tasks in such a synchronous manner, it's easy enough.

The web task creates a semaphore at startup. The web task gets data, loads it into some request/response object instance, along with its semaphore reference/pointer.  It fires it off to the queue and waits on the semaphore.  The DB task gets the object, reads the request, processes it, loads the response field/s with results, (or error messages:), and signals the semaphore.  The web task then runs on, knowing that the response is available.

That way, several web tasks can use the DB and it's input queue.

Forget the mutex stuff, you don't need any mutex, (well, there may well be one protecting the DB input producer-consumer queue but, presumably, that is an internal matter).

Answer (score 0):

In WebTask, after sending the msg to DBTask, it waits on a semephore (semTake) while in DBTask, after processing the Database request and data formating, it release a semephore(semGive). I think that should make your 2 tasks synchronized.